# Beschreibung extremer Langsamkeit

Tags: expression, synonym

Gibt es noch andere Worte/Redewendungen als "im Schneckentempo", um extreme Langsamkeit auszudrücken?

Comment: +1 interessante Frage! Im Englischen kann man dafür "glacial" nutzen, was ich sehr anschaulich finde - Gletscher sind nun mal extrem langsam. Das deutsche "glazial" hört sich dafür für mich einfach nur doof an.

Comment: Schnecken sind zwar langsam, aber "extrem langsam" trifft wohl eher auf die Kontinentalverschiebung zu.

Comment: "Mit der Geschwindigkeit eines Kontinents", gefällt mir. Setzt allerdings einen gewissen Bildungsstand voraus (nicht jeder weiß, dass sich Kontinente bewegen). Tatsächlich suche ich nach dem deutschen Äquivalent zu "glacial".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Vergleiche mit Schildkröten sind auch beliebt:

> Die Kultusministerkonferenz arbeitet gelegentlich mit dem Tempo einer Griechischen Landschildkröte.

Answer (score 5):

Das Eigenschaftswort

> gemächlich

drückt eine gewisse Langsamkeit aus – allerdings bedeutet es nicht *extrem* langsam.

Auch

> schleppend
>   *und*
>   schleichend

kann man für langsame Bewegungen und Entwicklungen verwenden. Das erste der beiden wird häufig im übertragenen Sinn für etwas verwendet, das bewusst verzögert wird.

Comment: "schleichend" hat für mich auch die Konnotation des Verborgenen: man bekommt es - bedingt durch die Langsamkeit oder auch aufgrund aktiver Bestrebungen - nicht mit. Siehe z.B. "schleichender Verfall der Bürgerrechte".

Answer (score 3):

Wenn tatsächlich eine Bewegung gemeint ist, dann passt auch

> kriechend

ganz gut. Bei übertragener Bedeutung könnte man auch

> unmerklich

sagen (z.B. *"The glacial moral decline"* - *"Der unmerkliche Verfall der Werte"*).

Answer (score 2):

Wenn "langsam" als Synonym für "träge" verwendet wird, geht

> [phlegmatisch](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/phlegmatisch)

Das würde sich dann aber eher auf die Person beziehen, die eine Arbeit ausführt, als auf den Arbeitsvorgang selbst.

Answer (score 2):

Naja, kannst theoretisch auch einfach ein Kunstwort verwenden:

> quasi-statisch

Oder du diskutierst es weg:

> vernachlässigbar

Comment: Wieso `vernachlässigbar`?

Comment: @userunknown: Wird oft im Technischen Umfeld benutzt. Wenn die Geschwindig "vernachlässigbar" ist, schalten Navis z.B. in einen statischen Modus. Dabei ist aber noch kein absoluter Stillstand erreicht. Es gibt immer noch eine gewisse Fortbewegung, aber die ist eben vernachlässigbar.

Comment: Ja, aber das Wort "Geschwindigkeit" kannst Du nicht weglassen. Es gibt auch vernachlässigbares Einkommen, vernachlässigbare Fehler usw.

Answer (score 1):

#### Redewendungen:

> - Als Ausruf, scherzhaft: *"Die spielen Beamtenmikado"* (wer sich zuerst bewegt hat verloren).
> - *"Was ist das für ein Bummelzug!"*

Comment: "Beamtenmikado" (und die Erklärung  dazu) sind fantastisch ! Ist es eine gebräuchliche Redewendung ?

Comment: Ich weiß nicht wie man es richtig nennt. Man kann sich nicht ganz drauf verlassen, dass es jmd. schon kennt, so dass man die Erläuterung in Klammern auf fragende Blicke nachschieben muss. Das macht es für manche Fälle ungeeignet.

Comment: Beamtenmikado should be well known.